# chrome.tabCapture.capture auto mutes the tab? Is there another method that doesn't mute?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture the audio of a website. I'm testing this on a youtube video. When I first capture the audio of the tab through chrome.extension.capture, the tab automatically mutes itself. Is there an API that doesn't do this or is there a way to unmute the tab while still capturing the audio?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't use this API but maybe your options for audio are incompatible. Also, check other versions of the browser, namely Canary, and see if the issue is reproducible.